# openpyxl how to display multiple values from a range

Tags: openpyxl

I made a program that outputted values from a range of numbers. And I tried to complicate it, to create an interface where I had to display the values from the button press. But for some reason I only get 1 last value. At the same time, everything works as it should through the print.

```py
def Excel123():

    wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename="resd1.xlsx")
    wb.active = 0
    sheet = wb.active

    for i in range(9, 14):
        x1 = i, sheet.cell(row=i, column=23).value
        print(i, sheet.cell(row=i, column=23).value)
    v.set(x1)
    v = StringVar()
    Label(root, textvariable=v).pack()
    Button(root, text="result", width=15, padx=15, pady=5, command=resd1).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: You don't assign the values to the GUI within the loop and you're also overwriting `v`, whatever it is.